# Jenkins: flutter pub get, cannot find git in PATH

Tags: git, docker, flutter, jenkins

I've built an Docker Image with a Dockerfile for Jenkins Container we use in our company in order to have several pipelines. In the image I've inserted several commands like Flutter, Sonar-Scanner, etc..
I have a couple of Flutter projects right now so I'm experimenting several things.
I've updated to the latest stable flutter SDK for Linux ( 2.2.3 )

The SCM phase starts correctly.

```
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.32.0'
```

The first step is just the command `flutter pub get`.
The problem is that after the update ( from `2.0.3`to `2.2.3`) I get this error: `Error: Unable to find git in your PATH`.

```
[Pipeline] sh
flutter pub get
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
```

**Additional information:**

We build in the master. I've added the git bin path (/usr/bin/path) to the PATH of the master machine, along with other paths ( like flutter itself ).
Before updating to the `2.2.3` the same pipeline worked fine.

I don't know what to do in order to solve this problem.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine

USER root

# RUN apt-get -y update; \
# apt-get -y install xz-utils unzip; \
RUN cd /opt; \
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_2.2.3-stable.tar.xz -O flutter_linux_2.2.3-stable.tar.xz; \
tar -xf flutter_linux_2.2.3-stable.tar.xz; \
mv flutter flutter_linux_2.2.3-stable; \
chmod -R 777 flutter_linux_2.2.3-stable; \
chown -R jenkins:jenkins flutter_linux_2.2.3-stable; \
rm flutter_linux_2.2.3-stable.tar.xz; \
wget https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.6.0.2311-linux.zip -O sonar-scanner-cli-4.6.0.2311-linux.zip; \
unzip sonar-scanner-cli-4.6.0.2311-linux.zip; \
chmod -R 777 sonar-scanner-4.6.0.2311-linux; \
chown -R jenkins:jenkins sonar-scanner-4.6.0.2311-linux; \
rm sonar-scanner-cli-4.6.0.2311-linux.zip; \
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.0/node-v14.16.0-linux-x64.tar.xz; \
tar -xf node-v14.16.0-linux-x64.tar.xz; \
mv node-v14.16.0-linux-x64 node14.16; \
chmod -R 777 node14.16; \
chown -R jenkins:jenkins node14.16; \
rm node-v14.16.0-linux-x64.tar.xz; \
cd ..

USER jenkins
```

PATH:

```
   /opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/flutter_linux_2.2.3-stable/bin:/opt/sonar-scanner-4.6.0.2311-linux/bin:/opt/flutter_linux_2.2.3-stable/.pub-cache/bin:/opt/node14.16/bin/:/usr/bin
```

WHICH GIT:

```
/usr/bin/git
```

Comment: Can you get/display the value of `PATH` before you make the failed `git` call? Also the output of `which git` would be valuable.

Comment: @eftshift0 I've added the information you've requested